# Как сохранить содержимое файла в std::string, используя его название?

Tags: c++, json, строки, файлы

Во время использования парсера json (https://github.com/gregjesl/simpleson) возникла проблема - насколько я понял, с его помощью можно обрабатывать строки, но не файлы. Поэтому у меня возникла потребность перенести содержимое файла в строку `std::string`. Почитал похожие вопросы - ответы разнятся. Файл довольно велик, поэтому вопрос скорости стоит. Важно, чтобы решение работало для расширения json (хотя с этим, я думаю проблем не будет).

В аргументы функции открытия хотелось бы передавать путь файла, а не объект потока, как это предлагали в других обсуждениях.
То есть выглядеть объявление должно так:
`std::string get_from_file(const char* path)`.

Итак, что же мне предпринять?

Comment: Ну, выясняете размер файла, создаете строку нужного размера и просто читаете весь файл в эту строку...

Comment: А зачем выяснять размер файла, если std::string - динамический массив?

Comment: @ЮрычBRO Чтобы произвести чтение "в один прием" это быстрее чем в цикле. (Меньше переходов  User_space<->kernel, чем в случае цикла.)

Comment: Похоже, я нашел нужный мне вариант: https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread2531910.html?ysclid=lfci16684s785231461#:~:text=%23include%20%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include%20%3Cfstream%3E%0A%23include%20%3Citerator%3E%0A%C2%A0%0Aint%20main()%0A%7B%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20std%3A%3Aifstream%20file(%22input.txt%22%2C%20std%3A%3Aios_base%3A%3Ain)%3B%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20std%3A%3Astring%20str%7Bstd%3A%3Aistreambuf_iterator%3Cchar%3E(file)%2C%20std%3A%3Aistreambuf_iterator%3Cchar%3E()%7D%3B%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20std%3A%3Acout%20%3C%3C%20str%20%3C%3C%20std%3A%3Aendl%3B%0A%7D

Comment: Так тоже можно. Интересно, кстати, посмотреть и сравнить скорости... Кстати, совершенно излишний флаг `in`, и я бы поставил флаг `binary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, есть решение, которое нашел на просторах инета автор вопроса, но есть и

> Файл довольно велик, поэтому вопрос скорости стоит

Код 1 с просторов Интернета.

```
ifstream file("LagreFile", ios_base::binary);
string str{istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), istreambuf_iterator<char>()};
```

Код 2, предложенный мною в комментарии.

```
ifstream file("LargeFile", ios_base::binary);
file.seekg(0,ios_base::end);
unsigned int sz = file.tellg();
string str(sz,' ');
file.seekg(0);
file.read(str.data(),sz);
```

Потом я записываю строку в другой файл, смотрю, что получилось... Естественно, время замеряю только то, что потрачено на чтение в память.

Все получается нормально, записанный файл соответствует считанному. Размер файла — примерно полтора гигабайта.

Первый код работает у на чтение меня примерно 10.4 с, второй — 1.4 с.

Да, есть еще, например, Код 3.

```
ifstream file("LargFile", ios_base::binary);
ostringstream str;
str << file.rdbuf();
```

После чего файл оказывается в строке `str.str()`. Этот код работает у меня примерно 8.0 с.

Comment: За скорость третьего кода обидно. :( Вы же в релизном билде проверяли?

Comment: Да, все компилировалось в командной строке, с одними и теми же ключами оптимизации etc. Основная проблема, как мне кажется — перераспределение памяти при чтении в строку: ей приходится постоянно увеличиваться, перераспределяясь и копируясь. Тут даже удвоение размера не поможет. Кстати, еще минус в том, что вполне может оказаться выделенной лишняя память — в среднем до половины размера файла.

Comment: Благодарю за версии, уже выбрал, работает, читает